# Void pointer to long

Tags: c

I'm studying the pthread library and i have a doubt. I hope you can help me.

I have a void * declared as:

```
void* threadid;
```

**threadid** is a pointer that contains a long value.
My prof told us that if i want the original long value i can do this ( suppose we are in the function passed to the thread )

```
long tid;
tid=(long)threadid;
```

However, to me , **threadid** should be dereference before applying the cast, since it's a pointer. Am i wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*However, to me , threadid should be dereference before applying the cast ?* No. Since **void pointer** has no types like `int/char/float` so you can't dereference it directly, first you need to typecast like  `(long*)threadid` and then dereference it like `*(long*)threadid`.

It should be

```
long tid;
tid = *(long*)threadid; /* valid, it should be long* bcz threadid is pointer */
```

And below one is invalid

```
tid = (long*)*threadid; /* in-valid bcz threadid is  void pointer &
                           void pointer need to cast first and then dereference  */
```

Comment: Thanks so much. However, why the code i posted work anyway ?

Comment: from the code you mentioned, `tid=(long)threadid;` here you are just assigning the address to `tid`, compiler may give you warning. but when you do `tid=(long)*threadid;` compiler gives the error.

Comment: @Qwerto because the pointer was interpreted as a long. While your `threadid` value was maybe something like 123456, the value of `tid` is now the value of the pointer, like 0x77654321

Comment: `tid=(long)threadid;` I hope this was not your intent i.e assigning address ? you want to assign value to `tid`. so make it like `tid  = *(long*)threadid;`